# Add class to all other divs when checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting, checkbox

EDIT AT BOTTOM

TL;DR I'm not sure how to add class properties to all the divs that don't have a class I selected with the checkbox.

I am trying to create a sorting script to a small guides list. So the idea is that my div tags will have describing classes attached to them such as:

```
<div class="guide-block WINDOWS UPDATE INSTALL">
```

The "windows, update and install" are the "describing" classes that will only be used for sorting purposes. A list with checkboxes on the side will allow the users to select the checkboxes that are relevant to what they need to find. Example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="install"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="update"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="windows"/>
```

The user selects the boxes relevant to their search and the divs that don't have a class that has been selected from the checkboxes will then have a class added with display: none; inside. This will make the irrelevant guides disappear (in theory).

I'm relatively new to java and jquery so I'm not sure what I am doing. I've pieced together script from other similar questions from this site to try and make the code I need. I've gotten the code to somewhat work. It will make the div that has the matching checkbox disappear when checked. I want the opposite. I want the divs that don't have that checked checkbox to disappear. And if I have a div with UPDATE and INSTALL on it, I need the code to recognize it has one selected and still stay. Because right now, if the div has both and I select one, it disappears because the other wasn't selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#install').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked)
        $("div.guide-block.install").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("div.guide-block.install").css("display", "none");
});
$('#update').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked)
        $("div.guide-block.update").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("div.guide-block.update").css("display", "none");
});
$('#windows').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked)
        $("div.guide-block.windows").css("display", "block");
    else
        $("div.guide-block.windows").css("display", "none");
});
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. Send me a guide on how to do it, whatever. I'm willing to learn this but I'm hitting a wall with my own knowledge and google search isn't understanding. Although, I'm not really sure what I'm looking for ha.

EDIT: I have rewritten the code as advised. Sadly this isn't working but I feel like I'm closer.

```
$('#install').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.install)').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please make it clear a bit more. This is still confusing.

Comment: added a TL;DR at the top

Comment: @Dakota: See my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a selector which has all the classes of options i.e. `windows`, `update` and `install`.

Also to establish relationship between elements I have used css class in small case.

```
<div class="guide-block windows update install">
  1. windows, update, install
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Select the checkboxes
  var checkboxes = $('.checkboxContainer :checkbox');  
  //bind the change event hanlder
  checkboxes.on('change', function() {    
    //get the checked checkboxes id, It return create an array
    var checkedCssClasses = checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
      return this.id;
    }).get();
    //For Debugging purpose, 
    console.clear();
    console.log(checkedCssClasses);    
    //Get all guideBlocks
    var guideBlock = $("div#guide-container .guide-block");    
    //Hide all block
    guideBlock.hide();
    //any checkbox is checked
    if (checkedCssClasses.length> 0) {
      //Create the selector for elements      
      checkedCssClasses = '.' + checkedCssClasses.join('.')      
      //Show filtered element
      guideBlock.filter(checkedCssClasses).show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.guide-block {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="guide-container">
  <div class="guide-block windows update install">
    1. windows, update, install
  </div>
  <div class="guide-block windows update">
    2. windows, update
  </div>
  <div class="guide-block install">
    3. install
  </div>
</div>
<div class="checkboxContainer">
  <input type="checkbox" id="install" />Install
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="update" />Update
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="windows" />Windows
</div>
```

Comment: I just figured out how to do it. I appreciate your help. I used the code you posted on the other post and modified it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: @Dakota, Go through this hopefully it fulfills your requirement

Comment: I just used this and it works better than mine. I changed the display: none; to block so that they show when the page loads. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Not the most glamorous solution here, but I believe it's the *simplest* for the sake of advancing your learning of jQuery. To me, jQuery is a lot about interacting with CSS, so I've included an interaction between jQuery and CSS to get the job done.

Basically, what we want is to hide all guide-blocks by default, and then use a SHOW- CSS class to show them as needed. The SHOW- classes work because they have higher CSS "specificity".

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#install').change(function () {
      if (this.checked)
          $("div#guide-container").addClass("SHOW-INSTALL");
      else
          $("div#guide-container").removeClass("SHOW-INSTALL");
  });
  $('#update').change(function () {
      if (this.checked)
          $("div#guide-container").addClass("SHOW-UPDATE");
      else
          $("div#guide-container").removeClass("SHOW-UPDATE");
  });
  $('#windows').change(function () {
      if (this.checked)
          $("div#guide-container").addClass("SHOW-WINDOWS");
      else
          $("div#guide-container").removeClass("SHOW-WINDOWS");
  });
});
```

```css
.guide-block {
  display: none;
}

.SHOW-WINDOWS>.guide-block.WINDOWS {
  display: block;
}
.SHOW-UPDATE>.guide-block.UPDATE {
  display: block;
}
.SHOW-INSTALL>.guide-block.INSTALL {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="guide-container">
  <div class="guide-block WINDOWS UPDATE INSTALL">
    1. windows, update, install
  </div>
  <div class="guide-block WINDOWS UPDATE">
    2. windows, update
  </div>
  <div class="guide-block INSTALL">
    3. install
  </div>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="install"/>Install<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="update"/>Update<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="windows"/>Windows
```

Comment: yes okay, this is close! What about showing all the guides before so they can see that there are guides there. Should I just have all the checkboxes checked when the page loads?

Comment: Actually is there a way to show all of the guides when the page loads, and have the checkboxes empty. This is so they can check-in the boxes they want and then the page will sort the guides.

This will be for people who aren't "tech savvy" so I want to make it as simple and intuitive as possible.

Comment: KISS - make your sorting a separate and obvious item, or you'll confuse your users, tech savvy or not.

Comment: As for default checked... This is all just HTML!
<input type="checkbox" id="install" checked/>
Add the classes to your container div: <div id="guide-container" class="SHOW-INSTALL SHOW-UPDATES SHOW-WINDOWS">

Comment: I have the sort taking up 30% on the left and the guides 70% on the right. So it should be obvious and on mobile it will be on top. I think I'm going down a rabbit hole that's too difficult. Is there a way to add classes to the divs that don't have the selected class?

Comment: I think my original Jquery code is messing people up

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why you want to add classes to the divs that aren't selected.. ? Please don't go jQuery crazy! It is exciting when you first get in to it, but focus your mind on CSS/HTML first. That said, for the purpose of doing sorting, you're probably looking to completely rewrite your code - I imagine you'd need to put your items in to an object array, and dynamically generate the view from JS code.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I appreciate all your help. I'll try to figure out a better way to do it

Comment: No worries. If it answers your original question, could you please mark my answer as correct?

Comment: I tried but it says I can't because I don't have 15 rep

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that what exactly you are looking for but as much I understood here is your solution.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#install').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
      $("div.guide-block.install").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("div.guide-block.install").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  $('#update').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
      $("div.guide-block.update").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("div.guide-block.update").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
  $('#windows').change(function () {
    if (!this.checked) {
      $("div.guide-block.windows").css("display", "block");
    } else {
      $("div.guide-block.windows").css("display", "none");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<div class="guide-block install">Install</div>
<div class="guide-block update">Update</div>
<div class="guide-block windows">Windows</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="install"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="update"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="windows"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do:

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtka8s64/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var chkboxArray = $(" input[type='checkbox']:checked").map(function() {
      return $(this).attr("id");
    }).get();
    $("div.guide-block").hide();
    for (var i = 0; i < chkboxArray.length; i++) {
      $("div.guide-block." + chkboxArray[i]).show();
    }


  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="guide-block windows update install">WINDOWS UPDATE INSTALL</div>
<div class="guide-block update install">UPDATE INSTALL</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="install" />Install
<input type="checkbox" id="update" />Update
<input type="checkbox" id="windows" />Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that got it working the way I wanted. It's not using css to hide the guides but it is hiding and showing them when the check and uncheck the checkbox. That's good enough for me right now! HUGE thanks to @Satpal !!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#install').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.install)').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.install)').show();
    }
});
$('#update').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.update)').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.update)').show();
    }
});
$('#windows').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.windows)').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('div.guide-block:not(.windows)').show();
    }
});
});
```